# Trying to change specific characters of a string in a Windows Form Application, C#

Tags: c#, string

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string name = textBox1.Text;

            if (textBox1.Text.Contains("l"))
            {
                textBox1.Text.Replace("l", "s");
            }
            string nameA = textBox1.Text;
            MessageBox.Show(nameA);
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, what I want to do is, have the user type in a name, have the "l" characters in the name changed to "s". And have the result shown in the messagebox when the button is pressed. However, No matter what I have tried, the "l" is never changed.

EDIT: Thanks guys, I can't believe it was something that stupid. Wow V_V

Answer (score 4):

```
textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Replace("l", "s");
```

Answer (score 2):

Since strings are immutable you have assign back the text after doing the replace.

Also you can just use `textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Replace("l", "s");` and avoid the `Contains` check, since if the replacement is not found in the `string` `Replace` will return the original text.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (name.Contains("l"))
{
    name = name.Replace("l", "s");
    textBox1.Text = name;
}

MessageBox.Show(name);
```